# ошибка при заполнение формы selenium python

Tags: python, input, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь применить Selenium к сайту https://binomo.com/ru, жму на кнопку ВОЙТИ, нахожу в выпадающем окне форму заполнения email, кликаю в нее, но при последующей попытке вбить туда какие либо данные, выдает ошибку. Кто знает как вылечить?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"D://htpthd//bin//probnik  //geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://binomo.com/ru/trading")
time.sleep(5)

elem_aut=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-md up btn-      link-secondary stretch']")
elem_aut.click()
elem_email=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ui-n-input[@class='form-control input']")
elem_email.click()
elem_email.send_keys("sввв")
```

выдает:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/htpthd/bin/probnik/cookies req.py", line 25, in <module>
elem_email.send_keys("s")
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
 return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
  self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <ui-n-input class="form-control input" name="email" type="email"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Либо может кто знает как использовать cookie в selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кнопка Вход

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn-holder"]').click()
```

выделить input

```
add_fuds = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]')
```

написать email

```
add_fuds.send_keys("asddf@asdf.com")
```